# Attach middleware to specific existing route

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to attach middleware to a specific route in Wordpress or just in PHP? I'd like to run a middleware function before allowing access to the uploads folder to check if the user has access to the file before allowing them to download it.

I come from a background in node.js/express so if it helps I'd like to do something like this:

```
app.use('/wp-content/uploads', function(req, res, next) {
    // do stuff with req and call next to continue,
    // or use res to end the request early. 
});
```

Comment: You cannot add any middleware because Wordpress does not have any request/response abstraction whatsoever. Only possibility is to write custom plugin that would react on given action. You can learn more about wp actions from the official docs

Answer (score 2):

There are various WordPress plugins for restricting access to content or downloads, mostly based on the logic of been registered or not and what privileges that user has.

Basic logic behind them is like this :

```
// Redirect guests
function guest_redirect() {
    $guest_routes = array(
        'member-login', 
        'member-account', 
        'member-register', 
        'member-password-lost', 
        'member-password-reset'
    );
    // Force login or registration
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_page($guest_routes) ) {
      wp_redirect( 'member-login' ); 
      exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'guest_redirect' );
```

Also, WordPress has REST API ([official doc here for your need](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/)). However, using own custom thing for production site using REST API without properly testing can be risky and complicated to use.

Answer (score 0):

From what I get about your use case from your description, you can solve your problem just using one of the many wordpress plugins already available, for example you can use a "downnload manager" to handle the upload and download of the contents: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/download-manager
or use something like https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-digital-downloads/

You can find more plugins here https://wordpress.org/plugins/

If you really want to write something custom, you can add use a RewriteRule to send all the requests for the uploads folder through a "protect.php" script, adding something like this in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ protect.php?filename=$1 [L,QSA]
```

In the protect.php script you can implement you custom logic to allow/forbid the access the the specific "filename"

To use the WP functions inside you custom protect.php file you should include the wp-load.php, more or less like this:

```
require_once(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/') . '/wp-load.php');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not sure why it took so long to get someone to answer. I did look at other plugins but for my needs I really need something custom. Also I am using Nginx, not Apache so could you show me an example in Nginx? Also would I be able to access the Wordpress library and the currently logged in user from this other script?

Comment: Never used Nginix, but you can read how to convert apache rules to nginix rules here: https://www.nginx.com/blog/converting-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules/